# Access vuex in data using asyncData

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I get id is undefined, So how to access vuex prop inside data object ?

```js
asyncData({ store }) {
    let id = store.state.auth.id
    return { id }
  },
```

```js
data: () => ({
    items: [
      {
        title: 'Profile',
        to: `profile/${this.id}`},
    ],
  }),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access vuex data directly with the data method

```
data: () => ({
    items: [
      {
        title: 'Profile',
        to: `profile/${this.$store.state.auth.id}`},
    ],
  }),
```

IN your example not able to understand why you used `asyncData`!